# How do I apply both RTP and UDP protocols to achieve audio streaming?

Tags: c++, mfc

How do I write a C++/MFC program to make a server as a bridge for clients to stream their audio? I have been told to use UDP and RTP protocol but due to my lack knowledge of media streaming, I couldn't make it work. What is relationship between UDP and RTP and steps needed for server to listen, accept and handle packet transfer between client to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As unwind said, generally RTP runs on top of UDP. It's called a conectionless protocol.

This is the specification of UDP: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt

An this is the specification of RTP: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1889.txt

You can find very useful information about RTP on [this](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/rtp/) site. There are different libraries and docs.

It's possible to write a "RTP forwarder" application.

Answer (score 1):

RTP generally runs on top of UDP, to get away from TCP's streaming behavior, TCP always delivers data in-order, which is not optimal for real-time applications.

It might be possible to do a "dumb" forwarder that is not RTP-aware, but instead is configured to e.g. accept UDP packets to port X, and forward all traffic to host:Y, packet by packet. Not sure if that works in practice, though.